# Mootools and CSS - p:first-letter does not function once JS is active

Tags: css, mootools

here's the fiddle setup:  [CSS pseudo class fails with JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/WhiteRau/hUNSB/1/)

for some reason the 'first-letter' psuedo-class works fine WITHOUT the JS.  as soon as i start pulling quotes with this:

```
$$('span.pullQuote').each(function(span) {
new Element('span',{ 'class': 'pulledQuote',
                      text: span.get('text')
                    }).inject(span.getParent(),'top');
});
```

it stops working...  why?  yank out the JS, leaving **everything** else alone and it works fine... and i re-read [the W3 spec on first-letter](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) and still don't see where this is breaking.

TIA.

WR!

*edit*: strangely, first-line, first-child, &c all work fine with the JS.  only first-letter stops working.

Comment: Interestingly, works fine for me in Chrome and IE just not Firefox. I do seem to recall that FF is picky about what it considers to be a `:first-letter`.

Comment: it works if you change the selector to span:first-letter - well, works differently in that it allows you to target it. it's probably the nested span tag

Comment: yeah.  weird, eh?  something that actually works in IE but not FF!?  i'm checking for a new star in the sky... at any rate, sounds like this might be a compatibility/standards issue... from FF... eep!  :P  but just in case, i'm going to leave this open for a bit... no offense guys.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and IE have no trouble with this setup, it's only Firefox that has issues. Unfortunately there is no easy fix. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246487/firefox-issue-with-elfirst-letter-when-elbefore-has-content) shows the same problem (though there it was generated content that was highlighting it).

It's related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214004) (I think). Try looking at the [reduced test case](http://test.csswg.org/suites/css2.1/nightly-unstable/html4/first-letter-selector-028.htm) in Firefox and it fails. This has been around for years now, so I wouldn't hold your breath waiting for it to get fixed. The only solution will be to *not* place the `pulledQuote` class as the first child of your paragraph.

Comment: craaaaaap.  but thanks.  :)  i have some ideas for a workaround sparking up...  wish me luck.